# Updating firebase cloud fields angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have been stuck on this for a while now and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I am trying to set the admin field to true for a specific user and it's not updating.

Here is my code:

```
SetUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      admin: user.admin = false
    }
    if(user.email == "master@mail.com"){
     this.afs.collection("users/").doc(`${user.uid}`)
     .set({ admin: true }, { merge: true })
     console.log(user.admin)
    }
    
    return userRef.set(userData, {
      merge: true
    })
  }
```

Comment: You have two calls to set() here, and neither of them have clear checks for errors.  Please add error checking, log the error, and edit the question to show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the following way to update fields of Firebase documents using Angular FireStore.

```
constructor(public fireStore: AngularFirestore) { }

SetUserData(user) {
   const userData: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      displayName: user.displayName,
      photoURL: user.photoURL,
      emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
      admin: user.admin == false
    }
    if(user.email === "master@mail.com") {
      this.fireStore.doc('users/' + userData.uid).update(userData);
      console.log(user.admin)
    }
 }
```